# In a WPF project, when opening SHBrowseForFolder, then "Create new folder" the app crash with no error

Tags: c#, wpf

I integrated the code snippet below in a WPF app. It works well to retrieve the path of the folder selected. However, with the new UI flag (bi.ulFlags = 0x00000040;) there is a button "Create new folder". When I press "Create new folder" the app crashes and nothing is available as an error or exception, even with the try...catch. I don't know how to proceed in such a case ?

It does not crash in any other case, it is really narrowed down to when I press "Create new folder" with the new UI. Until I figure out a way around it, I activated the flag for the old UI which does not show this option "Create new folder".

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SHBrowseForFolder(ref BROWSEINFO lpbi);

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool SHGetPathFromIDList(IntPtr pidl, StringBuilder pszPath);

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern void CoTaskMemFree(IntPtr pv);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct BROWSEINFO
    {
        public IntPtr hwndOwner;
        public IntPtr pidlRoot;
        public IntPtr pszDisplayName;
        public string lpszTitle;
        public uint ulFlags;
        public IntPtr lpfn;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public int iImage;
    }
}


private string SelectFolder(string windowTitle)
{
    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(260 * Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize);
    try
    {
        NativeMethods.BROWSEINFO bi = new NativeMethods.BROWSEINFO();
        bi.hwndOwner = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
        bi.lpszTitle = windowTitle;
        bi.ulFlags = 0x00000040;//bi.ulFlags = 0x00000000; //bi.ulFlags = 0x00000040; // BIF_USENEWUI, Enable the new UI style

        IntPtr pidl = NativeMethods.SHBrowseForFolder(ref bi);
        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(260);

        if (pidl != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            bool success = NativeMethods.SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, path);

            if (success)
            {
                string folderPath = path.ToString();
                return folderPath;
            }                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message); 
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    }

    return null; 
}
```

After activating Native code debugging, I found this error in the Windows Application event viewer :

> Faulting application name: app.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp:
> 0x8f5958c0 Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time
> stamp: 0x00000000 Exception code: 0xc000041d Fault offset: 0x04c00002
> Faulting process id: 0x31d8 Faulting application start time:
> 0x01d9c0600eb1538e Faulting application path: C:\app.exe Faulting
> module path: unknown Report Id: 1f791fc1-e8c6-481e-af3a-5a2a80d70d8c
> Faulting package full name:  Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Doesn't crash for me. Anything in event viewer? Or if you run under native debugger like WinDbg?

Comment: bi.pszDisplayName = buffer; is missing.  Weird, what else was left out?

Comment: I used "Activate native code debugging" Start in Debug mode. I Activated UI Analysis but nothing come up neither in the error, nor as an exception in the Visual Studio interface. The Diagnostic tools are also not showing any errors. Thus in the Windows events I found an error, I will add it to the main message. I also added "bi.pszDisplayName = buffer; " after the UI flag but that does not help.

Comment: @Dev1n.101 how do you call this `SelectFolder`? is there anything non-standard there?

Comment: I call it using the event of a Button click from the interface. Here is the exact code :         private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string folderPath = SelectFolder("Title", "Message");
            if (folderPath != "" && folderPath != null)
            { ...
            }
        }